# $HAM-NO-HAM$ problem: How do I show reduction from $HAMcircuit$ problem to the following problem?

Tags: computer-science

consider the following language: $HAM-NO-HAM=\{(G_1,G_2)|G_1, G_2\}$ are undirected graphs, $G_1$ has a Hamilton  and $G_2$ doesn't have one$\}$.

i need to decide wheter it's in $P, NP, CONP$ or none of the above.

If I'll show reductions from  $HAMcircuit$ and from  $NO-HAMcircuit$ I will get that  $HAM-NO-HAM$ is both $NPC$ and $coNPC$.

What is the best way for showing a reduction from the $HAMcircuit$ to $HAM-NO-HAM$?

I want somehow to copy it and then I would get the graph which does or doesn't have a  $HAMcircuit$ but I need to copy it again so it would fit the other other condition for the second graph.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reduce from HAM (or noHAM), just take the input graph and pair it with a fixed graph that you already know not to have (respectively, to have) a Hamiltonian circuit.

However, what these reductions prove is just that the problem is (co)NP-*hard*, not that it is *complete*.  To be complete, is must *both* be hard *and* actually be in (co)NP. And those same reductions show that your problem cannot be (co)NP unless NP=coNP, which is unknown but believed to be false.

Comment: sorry, I messed up the question. please see my edit.

Comment: Okay, new answer then.